# Accessing preferred key of Dictionary in order, with Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, dictionary, nsdictionary

In Objective-C, if I have a dictionary of video URLS which looks a bit like this:

```
NSDictionary *videoURLS = @{@"High":@"http://1234", @"Lowest":@"http://5678"};
```

Then I can access the preferred string (in this case, the highest quality video URL) like this:

```
NSString *highestQualityUrlString = videoURLS[@"Highest"] ?: videoURLS[@"High"] ?: videoURLS [@"Medium"]?: videoURLS[@"Low"]?:videoURLS[@"Lowest"];
```

How can I access a preferred string from a Swift Dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

The swift equivalent of `?:` for `nil` is the null coalescing operator `??`:

```
let highestQualityUrlString = videoURLS["Highest"] ?? videoURLS["High"] ?? videoURLS ["Medium"] ?? videoURLS["Low"] ?? videoURLS["Lowest"]
```

If you have a large list of items to scan, through, you could also use `flatMap` to simplify and clarify the code:

```
let keys = ["Highest", "High", "Medium", "Low", "Lowest"]
let highestQualityUrlString = keys.flatMap({ videoURLS[$0] }).first
```

The difference here, though, is that `??` is short-circuiting meaning that when `videoURLS["High"]` returned a value, videoURLS ["Medium"] was never called.  Swift 2.2 will support lazy flat maps, meaning you could do the following and obtain the same short circuiting behavior:

```
let keys = ["Highest", "High", "Medium", "Low", "Lowest"]
let highestQualityUrlString = keys.lazy.flatMap({ videoURLS[$0] }).first
```